# JavaScript optional chaining dynamic property

Tags: javascript, typescript, styled-components, optional-chaining

I am trying to access a dynamic property with safety provided by [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) that is available in TS. However it appears that this is not valid.

```
export const theme = {
  headers: {
    h1: {
    },
    h6: {
      color: '#828286'
    },
  },
}
console.info(theme?.headers?.['h6']?.color ?? '#000') //will pass
console.info(theme?.headers?.['h1']?.color ?? '#000') //will fail
```

## Error

```
Identifier expected.  TS1003

    10 |   const StyledTypography = styled.div`
    11 |     margin: 0;
  > 12 |     color: #000; ${({theme}) => theme?.headers?.[variant]?.color ?? '#000'}
       |                                                ^
    13 |   `
    14 |   return (
    15 |     <StyledTypography as={variant}>
```

It appears that the optional changing will apply to the optional `[]` as a type but not to the values inside.

How can I make this optional without having to do `[undefined || someDefaultValue]`?

Comment: How exactly do you get that error, i can't reproduce it.

Comment: You will need an environment where optional chaining is allowed. Then just use theme?.headers?.['h1']?.color ?? '#000'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create an interface that maps your theme object and pass the compiler type checking.

```
interface Headers {
    [key: string]: {
        [key: string]: string
    }
}

interface Theme {
    headers: Headers
}

const theme: Theme = {
  headers: {
    h1: {
    },
    h6: {
      color: '#828286'
    },
  },
}
console.info(theme?.headers?.['h6']?.color ?? '#000') //will pass
console.info(theme?.headers?.['h1']?.color ?? '#000')
```

Comment: Interesting idea, defining the types for it